# how can I read .xlsx files on an android app?

Tags: java, android, react-native, xlsx

I'm new to android app development, I'm trying to make a simple app, first, I need to read excel files (.xlsx and CSV) from the internal storage of the phone/tablet and work with the data but I don't find a way to do it, I want to read the file and put all the data on an array-like I used to do on other languages.

I'm trying to use XLSX and react-native-document-picker to achieve it, if somebody could help to just get first's cell data and show it on the console that would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a library like Apache POI.

For gradle add this:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.9'
```

or for maven this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And to use it, you can follow one of the many tutorials online. something like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel).